# [Angular]: Warning: No name was provided for external module '@clr/angular' in output.globals – guessing 'i1'

Tags: angular

I'm creating a library in Angular, and it requires dependency to `@clr/angular`.
In my `module.ts`, I have imported `ClarityModule`.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CloseBtnComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ClarityModule
  ],
  exports: [CloseBtnComponent]
})
```

In my `package.json`, I've added both `@clr/angular` and `@clr/icons`.

```
{
  "name": "close-btn",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.6",
    "@clr/angular": "^5.1.1",
    "@clr/icons": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"    
  }
}
```

In my `ng-package.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/close-btn",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

When I run command `ng build close-btn`, I got the following warning

[image]

It seems that I have to add something like this inside `ng-package.json`. But I'm not sure whether this is the right way, whether to put `clr-angular` or something else. Am I doing right or is there any best practice on this matter?

```
"umdModuleIds": {
  "@clr/angular": "clr-angular"
}
```